# SORTING XML elements properties out, search and sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, filepath

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE project PUBLIC "-//audacityproject-1.3.0//DTD//EN" "http://audacity.sourceforge.net/xml/audacityproject-1.3.0.dtd" >
<project xmlns="http://audacity.sourceforge.net/xml/" projname="wonton2_data" version="1.3.0" audacityversion="2.1.0" sel0="0.0000000000" sel1="0.0000000000" vpos="0" h="0.0000000000" zoom="0.3364562988" rate="44100.0" snapto="off" selectionformat="hh:mm:ss + milliseconds">
    <tags/>
    <wavetrack name="Audio Track" channel="0" linked="1" mute="0" solo="0" height="150" minimized="0" isSelected="0" rate="44100" gain="1.0" pan="0.0">
        <waveclip offset="0.00000000">
            <sequence maxsamples="262144" sampleformat="262159" numsamples="160491520">
                <waveblock start="0">
                    <simpleblockfile filename="e0000005.au" len="262144" min="-0.653625" max="0.686829" rms="0.04266"/>
                </waveblock>
                <waveblock start="262144">
                    <simpleblockfile filename="e0000317.au" len="262144" min="-0.010559" max="0.012848" rms="0.000999"/>
                </waveblock>....
```

issue. I have a recording that is extremely important. but there is a caviat all the files are broken up into several hundred smaller files (filename.au). I have the xml data that tells me what order these files go in. the recordings are very long and would take me probably a hundred hours or more to manually go through each xml copy filepath then look for locally. then place in order in DAW of my choice. maybe someone knows a way or is clever enough to help me build a tool or use javascript to sort this mess out.

I haven't really tried much to be honest I don't even know where to start.
actually maybe I do, but i have never worked with  XML so i second guess myself.

I need to grab that "simpleblockfile" filename tell "somethinG" to  find this file locally and place it in a folder in the order that the xml would provide

Comment: how big is the xml file? is there a chance you could post the complete XML file somewhere? Like some pastebin or github gist? Dropbox/Google drive download?

Comment: https://github.com/zephur/audacity--xml-data

Comment: I agree with @WBT. While it is certainly possible to parse the order of *.au files out, renumbering them, and writing them to a directory, it seems like just exporting out of audacity would be the right thing to do. Anything precluding this?

Comment: let me reiterate, the project folder/ xml / .au files are no longer in the same path. Audacity is unable to fetch the files from it's local folder. I'm looking for some kind of script that will parse the file name and then find them and move to a new folder. 

doing this one by one takes longer than you think.

search explorer for file name  a0000111.au
I have mupltiple .au projects so  sometimes there are multiple of the same 
.au filename. drag drop into DAW then then next on list...
and these are only at most 5 second clips

Comment: You definitely need to edit the question to more accurately reflect constraints.  Could you put the files on the path where Audacity thinks they could be, at least temporarily to open & export? If there are multiple files with the same name, how do you [expect a script to] disambiguate which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the question, your best bet appears to be [downloading Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/) and opening the XML file or a copy thereof with Audacity, then Export the assembled audio file in a place of your choosing.